# Rest service hitting the server two times after exact 5.1 and 10.1 minutes

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, rest, httpclient

I am using angular and Java spring boot. Whenever I hit the request(rest call) from angular 11 using the HTTP client module, the request gets duplicated/doubled at exact 5.1 and 10.1 mins. The network tab in the devs tool shows me only one request still I am getting duplicate requests on the server side.

Comment: Impossible to answer. So you’re saying your client side code does not make the request..?

Comment: That precision makes me wondering if you are not using some kind of scheduler, or some tool like Postman running automaticaly...

Comment: No there no scheduler running of any sort of. In fact is we change ISP its work fine and behave normally